# Why thrown exception is not correctly matched with catch block C#

Tags: c#, exception, visual-studio-debugging

Facing some weird issue with SocketException. Attached screenshot speaks more about it.

[image]

1. Why first catch block is not catching the exception while it is meant to catch the SocketException and thrown exceptions is again a SocketException.
2. Why control is going to second catch block which is meant to catch any exception ?

[Edit] : Adding screenshot in debug mode too

[image]

Comment: Out of curiousity, why are you debugging in release mode?

Comment: @CharlesMager I was under the impression that if you rethrow an exception, it gets caught at a higher level, not by the next catch block of the same try.

Comment: @user1666620 you're right,of course - sorry, I hadn't spotted where your break point was!

Comment: It's possible that the compiler or the JITter has realised that both catches perform the same job and optimised the first one out. What happens if (a) You debug in debug mode, or (b) you make them log different messages?

Answer (score 1):

Execution is *not* entering the second catch block, `try-catch` obviously doesn't work that way, the exception is thrown up the call stack, any following `catch` clauses are ignored.

It simply *looks* that way because you are debugging in *Release* mode which is not a good idea as the IDE is probably missing important debugging information and is therefore erroneously showing that execution halts when entering the second `catch` clause.

Do notice that halting at that point really makes no sense, if execution somehow made it into the second `catch` clause it would halt at the `throw` statement, not before.

To make it short, what's really going on is that execution is halting on the first `throw` and the IDE is not showing it correctly.

Moral of the story; do not debug in *Release* mode. If you are running *VS2015* it actually warns you that debugging experience in *Release* mode will be subpar (not sure if this warning appeared in previous versions).

**UPDATE**: It seems the issue is not related to debugging in *Release* mode as it still happens in *Debug* mode. Still, the point stands that debugging shouldn't be done in *Release* mode as funky stuff like this can happen. I would try cleaning the solution and see if that solves the problem. If it doesn't I wouldn't sweat it, the code is behaving correctly, its just a matter of the IDE not showing correctly where the execution is halting, no big deal.

Comment: Same thing happening in the debug mode. Added screenshot on debug mode too

Comment: @Praveen107 clean your solution, the IDE is simply showing the wrong position but your code is behaving correctly.

Comment: @Praveen107 Also, I understand that not edits have been done to the *Debug* build settings?